# Return value from new object callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following code

```
var foo = new Bar(function(callback){
    return callback  //async, use $q in angularjs
});
```

`new Bar()` has its properties and callback.
let say, property `foo.pro()` too call it, but how can I call `foo` to return the callback value?

Update
Bar() is actually firebase authentication object
code here

```
new FirebaseAuthClient(url, function(error, user){
  if (user) {
   console.log(user)  //if user logged in
  } else if(error) {
   console.log(error) //if login fail
  } else {
   console.log('user not login') //user not login
  }
});
```

So here, FirebaseAuthClient also has properties FirebaseAuthClient.login() and .logout()

I think this is not related to firebase but javascript so I skipped the code. Back to my question, how can I return the value of the callback?

If I set a var to foo
I can use `foo.login()` to call login but what I can call the return value of its callback?

Comment: I am not able to understand what `Bar()` does - could you provide a some sample code for it too? And I believe this has got nothing to do with AngularJs

Comment: That's entirely dependent on what `bar` does and how it handles the callback.

Comment: this may not be directly relevant to your questions. but if The callback is a function??? can you not just pass the `callback` instead of `function(callback){}` ???

Comment: @bingjie2680  I think it is just an argument and we can

Comment: you wouldn't "return" the callback at all, you just call it like that `callback();`. but it's still hard to say what the issue is here since I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: @basilikum I want to get the return value. Example `user`  `error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question was how to return something that was passed to a callback of an asynchronous function. The way to go would be to not return anything but processing the information inside the callback function:

```
function Bar(callback) {
       //some code
       var xy = 1;
       callback(xy);    
}


var foo = new Bar(function (arg) {
       doSomething(arg);    
});


function soSomething(arg) {
    //...
}
```

Now lets say you want to have a global variable and you want assign the argument of your callback function to it. In that case you can do that assignment just inside of `doSomething` and trigger a function that uses the global variable:

```
var myVar;

function Bar(callback) {
       //some code
       var xy = 1;
       callback(xy);    
}


var foo = new Bar(function (arg) {
       doSomething(arg);    
});


function soSomething(arg) {
    myVar = arg;
    goOn();
}

function goOn() {
    //do something with myVar
}
```

This is afaik as far as it goes with returning things from asynchronous functions.